# Node-Webkit do not load net image

Tags: html, node-webkit

I am using node-webkit develop an app,the page's image url was generateed from JavaScript and the JavaScript downloaded from internet.This is my JavaScript code:

```
 function updateMacInfo()
{
    var url=api_path+"/weixin/macData?id="+id;
    $.ajax({
        type : "get",
        async:true,
        url : url,
        dataType : "jsonp",
        jsonp: "callbackparam",
        jsonpCallback:"success_jsonpCallback3",
        success : function(pjson){
            var json=pjson[0];
            var qrcode=json.accountList;
            var banner=json.bannerUrls.split(",");
            var o1=$(".qrcode-union-list ul");
            for (var i = 0; i<qrcode.length; i++) {
                var li=tpl_qrcodeli.replace("{url}",qrcode[i].qrcodeUrl).replace("{nickName}",qrcode[i].nickName);
                if(i<5)
                    o1.append(li);
            };
            o1.addClass("count"+o1.find("li").length);
            o1.find("li:first").addClass("first");

            for (var i = 0; i<banner.length; i++) {
                $("#slides").append(tpl_bannerli.replace("{url}",banner[i]));
            };

            $("#slides").slidesjs({width: 1080,height: 500,play:{auto:true}});


        },
        error:function(){

        }
    });

}
```

This JavaScript generate the picture url,But the image can not display in Node-Webkit.At the same way, the page can display in Internet Explorer 8.0 and Google Chrome property.

How to set the Node-Webkit? and this is my setting:

```
"webkit": {    
    "plugin": true,
    "page-cache":false    
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is caused by the cache,and the Node-Webkit do not provide api to forbidden cache.Using statement clear cache in the **index.html**:

```
gui.App.clearCache();
```